# Why is data is getting deleted when merging two CSV files using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Hoping to get some insight on this issue, I am using Pandas to try and clean data then merge two records together. The code is below, it is successfully merging the two file headers but then deletes all my rows.

Before I can merge them, I have to rename the column of one file to match the other, then I need to strip out the string from the cell contents and finally convert the column from an object to an INT.

This is my first program, so it is a lot to bite off and I know I can do this in EXCEL in 2 minutes but want to automate it in the long term.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
os.chdir("c:/users/user/desktop/exercises")

fileA = pd.read_csv("./fileA.csv")
fileB = pd.read_csv("./fileB.csv")

fileA.loc[:,'step'].replace(regex=True,inplace=True, to_replace="Case ID Number - 00", value="") 
fileA = fileA.rename(columns={'step':'Case Number'}) 
fileA['Case Number'] = pd.to_numeric(contextor['Case Number'], errors='raise')
print(fileA.info())

#Merge works but then deletes all the table data
MERGE = fileA.merge(fileB,on='Case Number')
MERGE.to_csv('UPDATEDMERGE.csv')
```

Comment: it's telling you that no `Case Number`'s from fileA match up to fileB since the default merge is inner. I would check the dtypes and the actual data to see if everything aligns with your expectations

Comment: @aws_apprentice, Thank You! Turns out the numbers weren't matching in the native CSV file. I should have been calling .head() to test the whole time and I could have caught this way earlier.  Thank you again.